# REST API design for a "reset to defaults" operation

Tags: rest, api-design, http-method

I'm surprised to find so little mention of this dilemma online, and it makes me wonder if I'm totally missing something.

*Assume* I have a singleton resource called `Settings`. It is created on init/install of my web server, but certain users can modify it via a REST API, lets say `/settings` is my URI. I have a `GET` operation to retrieve the settings (as JSON), and a `PATCH` operation to set one or more of its values.

Now, I would like to let the user reset this resource (or maybe individual properties of it) to default - the default being "whatever value was used on init", before any `PATCH` calls were done. I can't seem to find any "best practice" approach for this, but here are the ones I have come up with:

1. Use a `DELETE` operation on the resource. It is after all idempotent, and its pretty clear (to me). But since the URI will still exist after `DELETE`, meaning the resource was neither removed nor moved to an inaccessible location, this contradicts the RESTful definition of `DELETE`.
2. Use a `POST` to a dedicated endpoint such as `/settings/reset` - I really dislike this one because its the most blatantly non-RESTful, as the verb is in the URI
3. Use the same `PATCH` operation, passing some stand-in for "default" such as a `null` value. The issue I have with this one is the outcome of the operation is different from the input (I set a property to `null`, then I get it and it has a string value)
4. Create a separate endpoint to `GET` the defaults, such as `/setings/defaults`, and then use the response in a `PATCH` to set to those values. This doesn't seem to contradict REST in any way, but it does require 2 API calls for seemingly one simple operation.

If one of the above *is* considered the best practice, or if there is one I haven't listed above, I'd love to hear about it.

**Edit:**

*My specific project has some attributes that simplify this question, but I didn't mention them originally because my aim was for this thread to be used as a reference for anyone in the future trying to solve the same problem. I'd like to make sure this discussion is generic enough to be useful to others, but specific enough to also be useful to me. For that, I will append the following.*

In my case, I am designing APIs for an existing product. It has a web interface for the average user, but also a REST (ish) API intended to meet the needs of developers who need to automate certain tasks *with* said product. In this oversimplified example, I might have the product deployed to a test environment on which i run various automated tests that modify the `/settings` and would like to run a cleanup script that resets `/settings` back to normal when I'm done.

The product is not SaaS (yet), and the APIs are not public (as in, anyone on the web can access them freely) - so the audience and thus the potential types of "clients" I may encounter is rather small - developers who use my product, that is deployed in their private data center or AWS EC2 machines, and need to write a script in whatever language to automate some task rather than doing it via UI.

What that means is that some technical considerations like caching are relevant. Human user considerations, like how consistent the API design is across various resources, and how easy it is to learn, are also relevant. But "can some 3rd party crawler identify the next actions it can perform from a given state" isn't so relevant (which is why we don't implement HATEOAS, or the `OPTIONS` method at all)

Comment: I'm also unaware of any 'best practice', so this would only be my personal opinion -  
1. Agree with your analysis - that doesn't seem like an intuitive behaviour of `DELETE` to me
2. Agree that it isn't REST by the book. However, I can immediately understand what it does
3. Agree again; also, not only is it un-intuitive, what if `null` is a valid value for one of the options? so if I send `option: null`, what do I mean? set it to `null`, or restore the default?
4. Does seem onerous

At the end of the day, REST isn't a religion; I'd go with what is easiest to understand; IMO option 2

Comment: "certain users can modify it via a REST API" - why would one user want to reset it while another one would not? Would that have implications for the other users who didn't reset it?

Comment: @codebrane lets say in the case of /settings, only a user with a "sysadmin" role/permission level would be allowed to do this. Not really relevant to the core of this question, I shouldn't have phrased it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's discuss your mentioned options first:

- 1: `DELETE` does not necessarily need to delete or remove the state contained in the resource targeted by the URI. It just requires that the mapping of target URI to the resource is removed, which means that a consecutive request on the same URI should not return the state of the resource further, if no other operation was performed on that URI in the meantime. As you want to reuse the URI pointing to the client's settings resource, this is probably not the correct approch.
- 2: REST doesn't care about the spelling of the URI as long as it is valid according to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). There is no such thing as RESTful or RESTless URI. The URI as a whole is a pointer to a resource and a client should refrain from extracting knowledge of it by parsing and interpreting it. Client and server should though make use of link relation names URIs are attached to. This way URIs can be changed anytime and client will remain to be able to interact with the service further. The presented URI however leaves an RPC kind of smell, which an automated client is totally unaware of.
- 3: `PATCH` is actually pretty-similar to patching done by code versioning tools. Here a client should precalculate the steps needed to transform a source document to its desired form and contain these instructions into a so called patch document. If this patch document is applied by someone with the state of a document that matches the version used by the patch document, the changes should be applied correctly. In any other cases the outcome is uncertain. While [application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) is very similar to the philosophy on a patch-document containing separate instructions, [application/merge-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) has a slightly different take on it by defining default rules (nulling out a property will lead to a removal, including a property will lead to its adding or update and leaving out properties will ignore these properties in the original document)
- 4: In this sense first retrieving the latest state from a resource and locally updating it/calculating the changes and then send the outcome to the server is probably the best approach of the ones listed. Here you should make use of [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) to guarantee that the changes are only applied on the version you recently downloaded and prevent issues by ruling out any intermediary changes done to that resource.

Basically, in a REST architecture the server offers a bunch of choices to a client that based on his task will chose one of the options and issue a request to the attached URI. Usually, the client is taught everything it needs to know by the server via form representations such as [HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html), [HAL forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) or [ION](https://ionspec.org/#forms).

In such an environment `settings` is, as you mentioned, a valid resource on its own, so is also a default settings resource. So, in order to allow a client to reset his settings it is just a matter of "copying" the content of the default settings resource to the target settings resource. If you want to be WebDAV compliant, which is just an extension of HTTP, you could use the [COPY HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.8) operation (also see other registered HTTP operations at [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml)). For plain HTTP clients though you might need a different approach so that any arbitrary HTTP clients will be able to reset settings to a desired default one.

How a server wants a client to perform that request can be taught via above mentioned form support. A very simplistic approach on the Web would be to send the client a HTML page with the settings pre-filled into the HTML form, maybe also allow the user to tweak his settings to his wishes beforehand, and then click a submit button to send the request to the URI present in the action attribute of the form, which can be any URI the server wants. As HTML only supports `POST` and `GET` in forms, on the Web you are restricted to `POST`.

One might think that just sending a payload containing the URI of the settings resource to reset and optionally the URI to the default settings to a dedicated endpoint via `POST` is enough and then let it perform its magic to reset the state to the default one. However, this approach does bypass caches and might let them believe that the old state is still valid. Caching in HTTP works as such that the de-facto URI of a resource is used as key and any non-safe operations performed on that URI will lead to an eviction of that stored content so that any consecutive requests would directly go to the server instead of being served by the cache instead. As you send the unsafe `POST`request to a dedicated resource (or endpoint in terms of RPC) you miss out on the capability to inform the cache about the modification of the actual settings resource.

As REST is just a generalization of the interaction model used on the human Web, it is no miracle that the same concepts used on the Web also apply onto the application domain level. While you can use HTML here as well, JSON-based formats such as [application/hal+json](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) or the above mentioned `HAL forms` or `ION` formats are probably more popular. In general, the more media-type your service is able to support, the more likely the server will be to server a multitude of clients.

In contrast to the human Web, where images, buttons and further stuff provide an [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of the respective control to a user, arbitrary clients, especially automated ones, usually don't coop with such affordances good. As such other ways to hint a client on the purpose of a URI or control element need to be provided, such as link relation names. While `<<`, `<`, `>`, `>>` may be used on a HTML page link to indicate first, previous, next and last elements in a collection, link relation here provide `first`, `prev`, `next` and `last` as alternatives. Such link relations should of course be either [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or at least follow the [Web linking extension approach](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288#section-2.1.2). A client looking up the URI on a `prev` relation will know the purpose of the URI as well as still be able to interact with the server if the URI ever changes. This is in essence also what HATEOAS is all about, using given controls to navigate the application though the state machine offered by the server.

Some general rules of thumb in designing applications for REST architectures are:

- Design the interaction as if you'd interact with a Web page on the human Web, or more formally as a state machine or [domain application protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=7m00s), as Jim Webber termed it, a client can run through
- Let servers teach clients on how requests need to look like via support of different form types
- APIs shouldn't use [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) but instead rely on content type negotiation
- The more media type your API or client supports the more likely it will be to interact with other peers

Long story short, in summary, a very basic approach is to offer a client a pre-filled form with all the data that makes up the default settings. The target URI of the action property targets the actual resource and thus also informs caches about the modification. This approach is on top also future-proof that clients will be served automatically with the new structure and properties a resource supports.

---

> ... so the audience and thus the potential types of "clients" I may encounter is rather small - developers who use my product, that is deployed in their private data center or AWS EC2 machines, and need to write a script in whatever language to automate some task rather than doing it via UI.

REST in the sense of Fielding's architectural style shines when there are a multitude of different clients interacting with your application and when there needs to be support for future evolution inherently integrated into the design. REST just gives you the flexibility to add new features down the road and well-behaved REST clients will just pick them up and continue. If you are either only interacting with a very limited set of clients, especially ones under your control, of if the likelihood of future changes are very small, REST might be overkill and not justify the additional overhead caused by the careful desing and implementation.

> ...  some technical considerations like caching are relevant. Human user considerations, like how consistent the API design is across various resources, and how easy it is to learn, are also relevant. But "can some 3rd party crawler identify the next actions it can perform from a given state" isn't so relevant ...

The term `API design` already indicates that a more RPC-like approach is desired where certain operations are exposed user can invoke to perform some tasks. This is all fine as long as you don't call it REST API from [Fielding's standpoint](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). The plain truth here is that there are hardly any applications/systems out there that really follow the REST architectural style but there are tons of "bad examples" who misuse the term REST and therefore indicate a wrong picture of the REST architecture, its purpose as well as its benefits and weaknesses. This is to some part a problem caused by people not reading Fielding's thesis (carefully) and partly due to the overall perference towards pragmatism and using/implementing shortcuts to get the job done ASAP.

In regards to the pragmatic take on "REST" it is hard to give an exact answer as everyone seems to understand different things about it. Most of those APIs rely on external documentation anyway, such as Swagger, OpenAPI and what not and here the URI seems to be the thing to give developers clue about the purpose. So a URI ending with `.../settings/reset` should be clear to most of the developers. Whether the URI has an RPC-smell to it or whether or not to follow the semantics of the respective HTTP operations, i.e. partial `PUT` or payloads within `GET`, is your design choice which you should document.

Comment: This is a fantastic response. I really appreciate the time and thought you've put into writing it, and it definitely helped me eliminate (or justify the elimination of) some of the approaches I listed. I've updated my original post with some more details on my use case - the use of forms in my case is irrelevant but logically I see how this would translate into what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

```
POST /settings HTTP/x.y
Content-Type: text/plain

Please restore the default settings
```

On the web, you'd be most likely to see this as a result of submitting a form; that form might be embedded within the representation of the /settings resource, or it might live in a separate document (that would depend on considerations like caching).  In that setting, the payload of the request might change:

```
POST /settings HTTP/x.y
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=restoreDefaults
```

---

On the other hand: if the semantics of this message were worth standardizing (ie: if many resources on the web should be expected to understand "restore defaults" the same way), then you would instead [register a definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1) for a new method token, pushing it through the standardization process and promoting adoption.

So it would be in this definition that we would specify, for instance, that the semantics of the method are idempotent but not safe, and also define any new headers that we might need.

---

> there is a bit in it that conflicts with this idea of using POST to reset "The only thing REST requires of methods is that they be uniformly defined for all resources". If most of my resources are typical CRUD collections, where it is universally accepted that POST will create a new resource of a given type

There's a tension here that you should pay attention to:

- *The* reference application for the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the world wide web.
- The only unsafe method supported by HTML forms was POST
- The Web was catastrophically successful

One of the ideas that powered this is that the interface was uniform -- a browser doesn't have to know if some identifier refers to a "collection resource" or a "member resource" or a document or an image or whatever.  Neither do intermediate components like caches and reverse proxies.  Everybody shares the same understanding of the self descriptive messages... even the deliberately vague ones like POST.

If you want a message with more specific semantics than POST, you register a definition for it.  This is, for instance, precisely what happened in the case of [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) -- somebody made the case that defining a new method with additional constraints on the semantics of the payload would allow a richer, more powerful general purpose components.

The same thing could happen with the semantics of CREATE, if someone were clever enough to sit down and make the case (again: how can general purpose components take advantage of the additional constraints on the semantics?)

But until then, those messages should be using POST, and general purpose components should *not* assume that POST has create semantics, because [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) doesn't provide those additional constraint.

Comment: Thank you for that link! However, there is a bit in it that conflicts with this idea of using `POST` to reset "The only thing REST requires of methods is that they be uniformly defined for all resources". If most of my resources are typical CRUD collections, where it is universally accepted that POST will create a new resource of a given type, but for the `/settings` resource it does something completely different (reset to defaults).

Comment: @motig88 POST is an all purpose method that needs to be used in case any of the other [HTTP operations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) semantics doesn't go well with the purpose of the request. Further, a new resource creation has to be indicated with the `Location` header in the response to a `POST` or `PUT` request.

Comment: @motig88 See edits in the new final section.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason thank you. I don't see myself proposing a new HTTP verb (at least, not yet) but what this tells me is I need to re-evaluate how I look at the semantics of `POST` and `PATCH`. My approach so far has been too naive, and hasn't utilized the full potential of these verbs. I'll do my homework and report back if I come to a conclusion.